# Bakery combinatorics problem.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider the problem : bakery make a dough for $m$ cakes after this chef-cook add $n$ cherries to dough. After cooking we have $m$ cakes. Suppose we randomly select one cake, what is the probability that this cake has $k$ cherries?

My attempt (edited) : I understand that my previous approach is bad.

Consider numerical example : $m=3,n=2,k=1$. So we have only $2$(!) possible variants of cherries positions $(2,0,0)$ and (1,1,0) (because we don't need to enumerate the cakes, so the cakes are non-ordered , i.e. $(0,2,0)$ = $(2,0,0)$), . Now we select one cake, there are only $2$ cakes with $1$ cherrie inside. But all number of cakes is : $6$, so the probability is : $\frac{2}{6}= \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: This is not clear.   You have given us no information regarding the distribution of the number of cherries in a cake.

Comment: The number of all cakes is $\binom{n+m-1}{n-1}?$  You just said that there are $m$ cakes.

Comment: @lulu I just want to find such probability (probability of choosing cake with $k$ cherries). 
I guess it can represented as $\{(a_{1} \dots a_{m}) | 0 \le a_{i} \le n \}$.

Comment: @saulspatz edited , thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  Seems quite confused.  As a (possibly helpful) suggestion:  work a numerical example.  Say $m=3$, $n=2$, $k=1$.  Surely you can just write that out entirely, no?

Comment: @lulu let me try to explain. Suppose we have set of sequences $\{(a_{1} \dots a_{m}\}$, such as $0 \le a_{i} \le n$ and $\sum_{i\le m} a_{i} = n\}$. The power of this set is $\binom{n+m-1}{m-1}$. Now we select one sequence $(a_{1} \dots a_{m})$, what is the probability that given sequence has $j$, such that $a_{j} = k$?

Comment: Just to mention one detail (among many):  your edit in no way clarifies your confusion regarding the number of cakes.  You say we have $m$ cakes in total, and then you say that the number of cakes with "summary $n$ cherries" (whatever that means) is $\binom {n+m-1}{n-1}$ but that number is, generally, a lot bigger than $m$...so, what did you mean?

Comment: In an earlier comment I suggested that you edit your post to work a clear, numerical example.  Not sure you have not done that.  Please do so.

Comment: I think (but am even remotely sure) that you are asking:  "suppose there are $m$ cakes.  Amongst all the cakes, there are exactly $n$ cherries.  What is the probability that a cake, chosen uniformly at random, has exactly $k$ cherries?"  If so, then you need to specify the distribution of cherries amongst the cakes.  One natural thought would be "Each cherry has an equal probability of being in each of the cakes, independent of the other cherries."  You, however, appear to want something else.  Something like "all possible $m-$tuples of cherries (that sum to $n$) are equally probable.  (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) That's a very odd and unphysical distribution though you are free to assume it if you want (I'd lose the verbiage about the cakes though, as it is extremely confusing).  If I have it right, can you edit your post to rewrite your problem along the lines I have proposed?  If not...well, then I have no idea.

Comment: @lulu edited, I hope it will be better!

Comment: @lulu you mean if we have a lot of cherries?

Comment: You still have not addressed the primary confusion:  do you want each of the possible $m-$ tuples to be equi-probable?  To stress:  that is a bizarre and unphysical assumption.  For a math problem, you are free to assume it, but you need to state that as an assumption!

Comment: I deleted an earlier comment because I had misunderstood what you had written.

Comment: To illustrate:  If there are $100$ cherries in the dough and I make two cakes, the probability that one cake has $0$ cherries is effectively $0$, but according to what I think is your assumption it would be $\frac 1{101}$, much too large.  I'd say it should be the same as tossing a coin and getting the same value ($H$ or $T$) $100$ times in a row.

Comment: @lulu the probability that one of them has $0$ cherries is $1/2^{100}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73093/discussion-between-openspace-and-lulu).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are saying, then I think you have a problem.  I'm going to restate the question here so you can see if I understand you.

We have $m$ cakes, and there are $n$ cherries randomly distributed throughout the cakes, in the sense that each cherry is equally likely to be in any one of the cakes.  A cake is chosen uniformly at random.  What is the probability that it contains exactly $k$ cherries?

Now you say, let $a_i$ be the number of cherries in cake $i.$  There are $\binom{n+m-1}{n-1}$ such sequences, and each is equally likely.  Suppose our chosen cake has exactly $k$ cherries.  Then the remaining $m-1$ cakes have $n-k$ cherries, and there are $\binom{n+m-k-2}{n-k-1}$ ways for that to happen, so the answer is $$\frac{\binom{n+m-k-1}{n-k-2}}{\binom{n+m-1}{n-1}}$$

The problem is that for this to work, each distribution of cherries has to be equally likely.  That is, if we have three cakes, and 20 cherries, it's just as likely that all the cherries are in the first cake as it is that 7 are in the first cake, 6 in the second, and 7 in the third, and that's not so.

I think you want to reason like this.  Each cherry has probability $1/m$ of being in the chosen cake, and probability $(m-1)/m$ of being in some other cake.  So, we're looking for the probability of exactly $k$ successes in $n$ Bernoulli trials, with probability of success $1/m$.